# Adding auto Increment Index when joining tables

Tags: mysql

I creating big table by joining multiple tables with the same suffix and table structure (columns). 
Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE `all_data` 
AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `a_data` 
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT * FROM `b_data` 
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT * FROM `c_data` 
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT * FROM `d_data`
                ) as X
```

The result seems to be what I was expecting to get except one thing, the final table 'all_data' doesn't contain an unique auto increment column. How do I need to change the SQL query to get MERGED TABLE with all unique values containing UNIQUE column ID?

Comment: Think you are looking for `CREATE TABLE all_data ( id PRIMARY  KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, .... ) ; INSERT INTO all_data SELECT * ...`  Also most likely you want to make it a TEMPORARY table..

Comment: Have a look at ROW_NUMBER(), if that's what you want to do